# how to solve the error The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered. when trying to extract data from excel

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, jet

I have an excel file that is sitting on my C drive and I would like to know how I can extract that data row by row validate it and insert into a sql table using openrowset. This is my query below

```
select * into crm_marketingdbclients_temptable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database= ;C:\Temp\HighEarners.xlsx;;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

I run this query and I keep getting an error that reads "The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered." I am using office 365 on a 64 bit machine

Comment: Jet 12.0? Do you mean ACE? Jet can't read `.xlsx` files; it's designed for Excel 97-2003 files (`xls`)

Answer (score 1):

Please use 64 bit engine, you are almost there.

```
SELECT
    *
INTO crm_marketingdbclients_temptable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database= ;C:\Temp\HighEarners.xlsx;;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943065/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine) if you still have error.